# Error assigning variable in ODI 12.2.1.4: java code works in 12.2.1.3

Tags: java, oracle, variables, plsql, oracle-data-integrator

There is a procedure with Java BeanShell technology that does the following:

```
**<@
String res="<?=p_valuexx?>";
@>**
```

Procedure returns lots of variables p_xxx (and one above including).

The next step in ODI does the variable assignment:

```
**<@=res@>**
```

this fails with the following error message:
        oracle.odi.runtime.agent.exception.ExecutionEngineException: com.sunopsis.tools.core.exception.SnpsSimpleMessageException:
    ODI-17517: Error during task interpretation.
         Task: 5
        com.sunopsis.tools.core.exception.SnpsSimpleNLSMessageException: ODI-17810: Error during BeanShell evaluation: BeanShell script
    error: Sourced file: inline evaluation of: `out.print(res) ; ;'' :
    Undefined argument: res  : at Line: 1 : in file: inline evaluation
    of:`out.print(res) ; ;'' : ( res ) 
         BSF info: null at line: 0 column: columnNo, Pre-execution code:
The same code is working just fine in 12.2.1.3